# Can the word "latency" be used to convey a sense of "delay"?

Tags: word-usage

According to "Merriam Webster dictionaries" "latency" means:

A state of temporary inactivity

But, "network latency" is a term used to indicate any kind of "delay" that happens in data communication over a network.

So I wanted to ask if the word can be used to mean "delay" though its true sense is "a state of inaction".

Comment: Yes, internet speed latency. Delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A state of temporary inactivity can also occur in a network(due to noise and interference) during data communication and this can cause delays and is therefore referred to as **network latency**. Network latency is the cause of delay and by extension it can be used for network delays.